# Error: my controller redirect me to another URL

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-data-jpa, spring-restcontroller, spring-rest

please any one can tell me why evrey time i'm trying to connect to **localhost:8080/users/get** I have been redirected automatically to another one **localhost:8080/login**.

**** I have only one controller in my app ****

thx all.

```
  @RestController
@RequestMapping(path = "users")
public class UserController {
    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;
    @GetMapping("/get")
    public List<User> getUsers() {
        System.out.println("hii");
        return userRepository.findAll();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please comment the below dependency from your pom.xml. Post that you will not be redirected to login page:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```